# How to take data N samples from MongoDB to form a graph representation on whole data set?

Tags: mongodb, time-series, aggregation-framework, timeserieschart

This is a sample document in our new app to store time-series data in MongoDB sub-document,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dcb6cacfb315e66b551a1a0"),
    "youtubeId" : "bIWShN9rKQU",
    "views" : [ 
        {
            "count" : 17506,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-08-12T13:31:00.002Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29576,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-14T13:32:00.216Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29579,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-15T13:33:00.197Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29582,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-16T13:34:00.192Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29586,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-17T13:35:00.180Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29595,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-19T13:36:00.190Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29597,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-20T13:37:00.206Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29604,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-21T13:38:00.228Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29606,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-22T13:39:00.218Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29613,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-24T13:40:00.201Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29619,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-25T13:41:00.250Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29624,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-27T13:42:00.103Z")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 29636,
            "at" : ISODate("2019-11-29T13:43:00.128Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I wanted to send this data in a web service consumed by a mobile application for plotting the graph, but I wanted to get only 10 objects in `views` array which should be the representation of *entire data set with respect to the time*. But it should be 10 data irrespective of the size of the array.

How can I take 10 data from the entire data set like this by using the `at` timestamp field to create a representation of the whole data?

Comment: Can you please explain little bit about what these mean: "...I wanted to get only 10 objects in views array...",  "But it should be 5 data irrespective of the size of the array", and "How can I take 10 data from the entire data set...". May be an example?

Comment: @prasad_ In the above example views is an object array, which has times from 2019-08-12T13:31:00.002Z to 2019-11-29T13:43:00.128Z (13 records as 1/ minute), so that 5 samples from that means one record per every 2 minutes approximately

Comment: I posted an aggregation query; please let me know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above example views is an object array, which has times from
>   2019-08-12T13:31:00.002Z to 2019-11-29T13:43:00.128Z (13 records as 1/
>   minute), so that 5 samples from that means one record per every 2
>   minutes approximately

```
var noOfSamples = 5

db.test.aggregate( [
{ 
  $addFields: { 
      indexes: { 
          $range: [ 0, 
                    { $size: "$views" }, 
                    { $ceil: { $divide: [ { $size: "$views" }, noOfSamples ] } } 
                  ]
      } 
  }
},
{ 
  $project: { 
      sample: { 
          $map: {
              input: "$indexes",
                 as: "ix",
                 in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$views", "$$ix" ] }
          }
      }
   }
}
] )
```

---

**NOTES:**

The number of samples you want is 5, `noOfSamples`. The size of the `views` array is `13`.

Number of elements in `views` is divided by `noOfSamples`; in this case you get a value of `2.6`. The `$ceil` rounds it to the next rounded integer, which is `3` (lets call it "step"). The `$range` operator gives you an array of numbers between 0 and 12 with a step of 3 (0 is the `views` array's first index, 12 is the array's highest index). With the aggregation's first stage you get an array called as `indexes`: `[ 0, 3, 6, 9, 12 ]`.

In the second stage of the aggregation, you get the `views` array elements by their indexes, using the `indexes` generated in the previous stage. The `$map` aggregation array operator *maps* the generated index from `indexes` to the `views` array element - so you get the five elements from `views` array as sample.

Comment: This answer is really great, it would really be a great help if you could explain the logic a bit?

Comment: I added some details as "NOTES" to the answer. Hope it helps.